# Argument of type '{ relativeTo: Router; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NavigationExtras'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Compilation error while adding relative path.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ServersService } from '../servers.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private serversService: ServersService, private route: Router, private acRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

onEditServer()
  {
        this.route.navigate(['edit'], {relativeTo: this.route});
  }
```

Error was on this part `{relativeTo: this.route}`.

**Error Description:**

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '{ relativeTo: Router; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NavigationExtras'.
Types of property 'relativeTo' are incompatible.
Type 'Router' is not assignable to type 'ActivatedRoute'.
Property 'params' is missing in type 'Router'.
```

Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **`acRoute`** instead of **`route`** in the 2nd parameter

```
  onEditServer() {
    this.route.navigate(['edit'], { relativeTo: this.acRoute});
  }
```

Comment: i am not sure, may be downvoter would have thought i have pasted the same code. mark if this helped